# mongoose - insert document with related

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models connected in the following way:

```
var ModelASchema = new Schema({
  modelB:  { type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'ModelB', required : true},
});

var ModelBSchema = new Schema({
  text: { type: String }
});
```

I am trying to save a new instance of ModelA with a new instance of ModelB inside it :

```
var modelA = new ModelA({
        modelB: new ModelB({text: 'new text'})
    })
modelA.save(function(err){})
```

The weird thing is that ModelA is being saved to the DB with an ObjectID, but the new instance of ModelB isn't being saved.

Is there a way to insert both documents and connect them with a single save or I must first save ModelB and then save it into ModelA.

Answer (score 0):

You must first save `ModelB` as because you are used as reference in `ModelA`you can not save it in this manner.

When you are saving `ModelA` it doesn't find refrence of `ModelB` that why it save only `ModelA` with _id

Comment: So as far as I understand there is no other way but to use ModelB as embedded document of ModelA

Comment: yes you can also do this but according to your schema u first save modelB then modelA